# ArcGIS - where is the zip & unzip toolbox available for download?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, download

ESRI mentions a zip & unzip toolbox available for download (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geoprocessing/python_2126079299.htm) Unfortunately the direct link provided is out of date & I can't seem to find it searching through ESRI's sites or anywhere else.  Does anyone know where ESRI hid it?

Answer (score 1):

You could reproduce the toolbox yourself pretty trivially: the parameters are described in that documentation and the source for [`zip.py`](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geoprocessing/zip_python_script.htm) and [`unzip.py`](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geoprocessing/unzip_python_script.htm) are both online.